# ASP.Net Open office XML Set the values of a cell

Tags: asp.net, excel, validation

I am using ASP.Net and Open office XML and I have been able to set the headers of the excel file.
However, I want to set the value to cells from say D2 to D1000 in a drop down fashion i.e. that the user can only select from a predefined list of values as in a drop down list.
How do I accomplish this?
The code for creating the excel is

```
List<ExcelExport> mpList = new List<ExcelExport>();
    DataTable dt = ListToDataTable(mpList);    
    string attachment = string.Format("attachment;filename={0}-{1}.xlsx", ddlHealthFacility.SelectedItem.Text + " Excel export ", " ");
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        //Create the worksheet
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Monthly Plan");
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);  
        Byte[] fileBytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: You're looking for the API to associate a "Data Validity" list with a range of cells.  (See the wiki article on [validating cell contents](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Validating_cell_contents).)  I'm not sure what the API is, but if you add the keywords "data validity" to your question and/or title you might have a better chance of attracting someone who does know.  Also, are you using OpenOffice to create a .xls file?  That can be pretty buggy - it's much better to create an .ods file whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you intend to ask about Office Open XML (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)?  If so, then your question is not related to `openoffice.org`, so the tag should be `excel` instead.

Comment: OK. I just changed it. Thank you.